# the advantage of nullable variable in memory allocation C#

Tags: c#, variables, nullable

I had read some article explain about `nullable<T>` type variable, so far I not found any article explain the effect of `nullable<T>` type variable compare with non-nullable type variable.

is that `nullable<T>` type variable will consume lesser memory allocation? or both of them is same

**add-on**

so we are not necessary to use `nullable<T>` for every variable when it have no possibility to be null?

Comment: Nullable data types cover the entire range of their non-nullable counterpart, there is no way for them to occupy less memory, or even the same amount of memory, because the information about the value being `null` has to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the `Nullable<T>` type, then it will always use more memory than the equivalent non-nullable type.

Both are value types and so can be stored e.g. on the stack when used as parameters or local variables, or as individual elements within a contiguous block of memory (i.e. as an array), which can *in some situations* improve memory usage characteristics. In other words, with `Nullable<T>` you get some reference type semantics, without some of the storage-related drawbacks.

But an instance of `Nullable<T>` necessarily contains both the nominal value (even when the effective value of the instance is `null`, the storage for the non-nullable type still exists), along with a flag indicating whether or not the instance should be treated as a `null` value. Obviously "value plus a flag" will take more memory than just "value".

Note that [the implementation of `Nullable<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e), at least from a storage perspective, looks like this:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private bool hasValue; 
    internal T value;
}
```

You can clearly see the value and the flag here. The non-nullable equivalent for any variable of type `T` would of course have only the value. The extra `bool` represents an additional memory requirement.

Thus, for any value type `T`, an instance of `Nullable<T>` will take up more memory than an instance of `T`.